# Pairwise orthogonality for partitions of unity in a *-algebra

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, counterexamples

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a $*$-algebra with unit $1_{\mathcal{A}}$. As in the $\mathrm{C}^*$-setting, a projection is an element $p\in\mathcal{A}$ such that $p=p^2=p^*$. A *partition* of unity is a finite set of projections $\{p_i\}_{i=1}^N\subset \mathcal{A}$ such that:
$$\sum_{i=1}^N p_i=1_{\mathcal{A}}.$$

> Is there an example of a partition of unity such that the projections
> are *not* pairwise-orthogonal?

---

If $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebra (or presumably, if there exists a *-representation $\pi(\mathcal{A})\subset B(\mathsf{H})$, or something similarly and suitably embedding the partition of unity in a $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebra), then it is well known that the projections in a partition of unity are pairwise-orthogonal. In the theory of quantum permutation groups, there is an approach that uses universal *-algebras generated by various partitions of unity, and because it is believed that the answer to the above question is yes, the orthogonality relations $p_ip_j=\delta_{ij}\,p_i$ are added at that point (where in the universal $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebra approach, such relations are automatic).

I have asked some people for an explicit example/counterexample and thus far nobody knows beyond "person $X$ says there is one".

Comment: This appears as Problem 5.2 in [Algebras, Synchronous Games and Chromatic Numbers of Graphs](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.00960). A few paragraphs before that, it is noted that you will at least need 4 projections for a potential counterexample. The paper is from 2017, and I don't know if this has been resolved since then.

Comment: @TobiasFritz IIRC person $X$ is a coauthor on that paper. I wonder if the people I asked confused [17] with an answer to Problem 5.2? Or maybe person $X$ found a counterexample since 2017. Thanks for comment.

Comment: The counterexample attributed in that paper to Heydar Radjavi should at least give enough a somehwat non-explicit counterexampe: it implies the desired non-orthogonality in the algebra with presentation $\langle p_1, \dots, p_4 \mid p_i^2 = p_i \rangle$, and that's enough because this algebra is clearly a $*$-algebra if you make the generators self-adjoint. So it seems to me that the authors could immediately have resolved Problem 5.2 in the negative. Am I missing something?

Comment: @TobiasFritz I don't think an algebra necessarily admits an involution.

Comment: Of course not, but the with that presentation clearly does (you just reverse all words), no?

Comment: @TobiasFritz I am not sure. I guess my question could include... does anyone know Radjavi's example?

Comment: Well, all I'm saying is that having an example as claimed in the paper would be enough to answer the question. To add further to the mystery: the orthogonality holds automatically for all $N$ in every finite-dimensional algebra (without involution). This is because [it holds in matrix algebras](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/115067/necessary-and-sufficient-conditions-for-a-sum-of-idempotents-to-be-idempotent), and every finite-dimensional algebra embeds into a matrix algebra.

Comment: @TobiasFritz I think you also need an additional relation stating $p_1 + \cdots + p_4 = 1$? But yeah, all the relations are preserved under reversal of words, so reversing words indeed defines an involution on it. I wonder why the authors didn’t notice this.

Comment: @DavidGao: whoops, right, I indeed forgot to include the most important relation :)

Comment: I’m thinking it might be possible to directly prove, using perhaps a combinatorial argument, in the free $\ast$-algebra generated by four self-adjoint idempotents $p_1, \cdots, p_4$ with relation $p_1 + \cdots + p_4 = 1$, you have $p_1p_2 \neq 0$. The algebra in question is the free product of four copies of $\mathbb{C}^2$, mod the kernel generated by $p_1 + \cdots + p_4 - 1$. It’s just a matter of showing $p_1p_2$ is not in the kernel - feels certainly doable, no?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following arguments are perhaps not as explicit as you might like, but at least they show that orthogonality is not automatic for $N \ge 5$.

- Consider first the purely algebraic case without involution. For this, Example 4.2 of a [paper by Bart, Ehrhardt and Silbermann](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01206409) gives non-orthogonal idempotents $p_1, \ldots, p_4$ summing to $0$. Trivailly, using $p_5 = 1$ in addition results in five idempotents summing to $1$ and violating the orthogonality.
- Now we have a complex algebra with idempotents $p_1, \dots, p_5$ such that $p_1 + \cdots + p_5 = 1$, but such that the orthogonality relation $p_i p_j = 0$ for $i \neq j$ does not hold. This implies that the orthogonality does not hold in the universal algebra
  $$\langle p_1, \dots, p_5 \mid p_i^2 = p_i, \; p_1 + \cdots + p_5 = 1\rangle$$
  either.
  But this universal algebra is such that the relations only involve palindromes, and therefore we can define an involution $*$ by reversing every word in the generators and extending conjugate linearly. In particular, this makes the generators $p_i$ become self-adjoint, and we therefore have the desired counterexample.

It seems plausible that the construction of Bart, Ehrhardt and Silbermann could be adapted to produce $p_1 + \dots + p_4 = 1$ already, in which case a counterexample with $N = 4$ would follow.

Comment: Example 4.2 gives four projections $P,Q,R,S$ in $L(\ell^\infty(\mathbb{R}))$. I am happy with the unital algebra generated by these, say $A_0=\operatorname{alg}\langle P,Q,R,S,I\rangle$. I am tentative about the *-operation here, and in the two universal algebras above and in the comments. Essentially, I see ye choosing as the involution a homomorphism $A_0\to A_0^{\text{opp}}$. And my concern is that it feels like you can always do this... which seems wrong. Perhaps the point I am missing is that if $A$ is universal and $A^{\text{op}}$ satisfies same relations then there is a homomorphism...

Comment: by the universal property. And that feels OK. But surely in that case we should be able to put the *-structure on $\operatorname{alg}\langle P,Q,R,S,I\rangle\subseteq L(\ell^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}))$ and just have an explicit counterexample in *-$\operatorname{alg}\langle P,Q,R,S,I\rangle\subseteq L(\ell^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}))$? It must be the case that for algebras that do not admit a * that the opposite algebra is really very different.

Comment: Yes. the involution amounts to choosing a homomorphism to its (complex conjugate) opposite algebra, and this follows from an application of the universal property defined by the presentation. You cannot always do this, for example for $\langle a, b \mid a b = 1\rangle$ you clearly do not get a homomorphism to the opposite algebra by mapping each generator to itself. As mentioned in the answer, it works in the case at hand because the relations only involve palindromes.

Comment: Great, thank you. So, if I don't want to get down in the weeds in $A=*\text{-}\operatorname{alg}\langle P,Q,R,S,I\rangle$ and $A^{\text{opp}}$, but still be fussy, with $B$ the universal *-algebra in this question, and by the universal property I have *-homomorphisms $\pi:B\to A$ and $\tau:B\to B^{\text{opp}}$, and I can define an involution on $A$ by: $\pi(f)^*=\pi(\tau(f))$... which is just exactly what you are saying.

Comment: Uhm not exactly, I'm not trying to construct an involution on $A$, but only on the universal algebra $B$ (where the involution is your $\tau$, provided that your opp also involves complex conjugation in order to make the involution conjugate linear). Like you, I'm also skeptical about $A$ having an involution. Having an involution on $B$ is enough because the generating projections in $B$ are non-orthogonal, by virtue of the $\pi(p_i)$ being non-orthogonal in $A$.

Comment: OK I understand that the $\pi$ is just an algebra homomorphism.

Comment: The latest (surely stupid) confusion: why don't the $P,Q,R,S$ define bounded operators on $L^2([0,1])$...

Comment: It looks like they do, right? So you can even get a non-orthogonal partition of unity (consisting of non-self-adjoint idempotents) in a C*-algebra.

Comment: .... but the same paper claims you cannot sum four non-trivial idempotents to zero in a Banach algebra... I am actually giving a talk in a small seminar today we might tease this out there.

Comment: Good point, then I'm confused as well... Perhaps let us know if you figure it out?

Comment: Ah yes, I am stupid. Two of those maps have a $-1-x$ and they are not operators on that Hilbert space... and if we change the Hilbert space appropriately then they are not bounded.

Comment: They take also not take bounded but all real valued functions.